# Alguém sabe onde está o erro neste código?

Tags: php, pdo, upload

O erro que me é gerado é o seguinte:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Algúem sabe me dizer como resolver?
Segundo o erro, está nesta parte:

```
$extensoes_aceitas = array('bmp' ,'png', 'svg', 'jpeg', 'jpg');
$extensao = end(explode('.', $_FILES['foto']['name']));
```

Segue o código...

```
if ($acao == 'incluir'):

            $nome_foto = 'padrao.jpg';
            if(isset($_FILES['foto']) && $_FILES['foto']['size'] > 0):  

                $extensoes_aceitas = array('bmp' ,'png', 'svg', 'jpeg', 'jpg');
                $extensao = end(explode('.', $_FILES['foto']['name']));

                 // Validamos se a extensão do arquivo é aceita
                if (array_search($extensao, $extensoes_aceitas) === false):
                   echo "<h1>Extensão Inválida!</h1>";
                   exit;
                endif;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está no uso do `end()`.

O manual é seu amigo:

```
mixed end ( array &$array )
```

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.end.php

A função espera específicamente um *array* passado por referência (`&`) mas você está passando uma expressão.

Uma solução seria guardar o resultado do explode numa variável para que a referência funcione:

```
$partes = explode('.', $_FILES['foto']['name'])
$extensao = end($partes);
```

Mas ainda assim é um mau uso do `end()`, pois o PHP tem funções próprias para saber partes de nome de arquivo:

```
$partes = pathinfo($_FILES['foto']['name']);
$extensao = $partes['extension'];
```

> http://php.net/pathinfo

Aproveitando, não tem razão para fazer um `array_search`, basta isso:

```
if (!in_array($extensao, $extensoes_aceitas)):
```

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php

Comment: Me diz uma coisa, dessa forma eu consigo fazer upload de outros arquivos como pdf por exemplo?

Comment: Upload você consegue de qq coisa, esse código seu só roda depois do upload feito. O máximo que ele serve é pra vc descartar algo que não queira depois de upado.